# How to print while text-to-speech

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I want my python program to print while it's converting text-to-speech, but it takes a while to take input after speaking... please suggest any ideas (:

```
import pyttsx3
import math


speaker = pyttsx3.init()

speaker.say("Enter operator")
speaker.runAndWait()

print("Valid Operators:\n"
      "type \"add\" for adding\n"
      "type \"subtract\" for subtracting\n"
      "type \"divide\" for dividing\n"
      "type \"multiply\" for multiplying\n"
      "type \"Square root\" for square-root\n"
      "type \"Square\" for square of a number\n")
op = input("Enter your operator:\n")
```

Comment: You could spin the speaking off to a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

````
import pyttsx3
import math
import threading

speaker = pyttsx3.init()

def say_thread(s):
    speaker.say(s)
    speaker.runAndWait()

def say(s)
    x = threading.Thread(target=say_thread, args=("Enter operation",))
    x.start()

say( "Enter operation" )
print("Valid Operators:\n"
      "type \"add\" for adding\n"
      "type \"subtract\" for subtracting\n"
      "type \"divide\" for dividing\n"
      "type \"multiply\" for multiplying\n"
      "type \"Square root\" for square-root\n"
      "type \"Square\" for square of a number\n")
op = input("Enter your operator:\n")```
````